# C++ subclasses modular functions

Tags: c++, subclass

Sorry, I decided to radically update the question given the code was riddled with my errors and didn't convey my point.

I wanted to see whether or not the below is viable:

Here's an example that can be compiled:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class TestA
{
    public:
        int A;

        TestA(){A = 1;}
        const TestA &operator=(const TestA &Copy)
        {
            A = Copy.A;
        }
};

class TestB : public TestA
{
    public:
        using TestA::operator=;
        void AdvancedFunction1(){A = A + A;}
};



int main()
{
    TestA Test;
    TestB *Alt;
    TestB Alt2;

    Alt = (TestB *)&Test;

    printf("%d!\n",Test.A);
    Alt->AdvancedFunction1();

    printf("%d!\n",Test.A);

    Test = Alt2;

    printf("%d!\n",Test.A);

    return 0;
}
```

Given, that TestB can (with casting) point to TestA, and can successfully modify TestA, is this a viable concept? It seems to work so, what are the pitfalls? (I know people say it's wrong but what is it that is *specifically* wrong with it aside from 'convention'?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vi·a·ble

Adjective/ˈvīəbəl/

1. Capable of working successfully; feasible

If it works, it's viable.

In your case, it works. However, consider these 2 scenariosn:

-You might add virtual functions. That will cause it to crash.

-You might change `AdvancedFunction1()` so that it operates on members of the class TestB, which will result in undefined behavior, because your object is not of the type TestB and does not have the members of a TestB.

EDIT:

Crash code:

```
class TestA
{
    public:
        int A;

        TestA(){A = 1;}
        const TestA &operator=(const TestA &Copy)
        {
            A = Copy.A;
        return *this;
        }
};

class TestB : public TestA
{
    public:
        using TestA::operator=;
        void AdvancedFunction1(){A = A + A;}
    virtual void f()
    {
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TestA Test;
    TestB *Alt;
    Alt = (TestB *)&Test;
    Alt->AdvancedFunction1();
    Alt->f(); //crash here

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the kind of answer I was looking for. Someone who highlights the specific vulnerabilities of the given technique. Testing it by adding a virtual function to TestA doesn't result in a crash.

Comment: Yes. The only downside (depending on view) is it called base's function rather than TestB's, but setting it to non-virtual resolved that. That is, even if TestA and TestB both have virtual and I call it. I'll try mixing virtual with non-virtual.

Comment: Actually I was wrong, add a virtual function to TestB and call it.

Comment: Adding a virtual function to TestB (but not TestA) indeed results in a crash, but likely due to TestA not having a Vtable. - I stand corrected, crashes if virtual is called above base irregardless of whether or not TestA has other virtual functions.

Comment: The problem is that it's very subtly **not** viable. Strict aliasing rules allow the compiler to assume (in spite of all the indications to the contrary), that `AdvancedFunction1` does *not* have access to `Test`. It will work 99% of time. Until one day the compiler decides to load `Test.A` to a register, than call `AdvancedFunction1` and than use the value from register, silently ignoring anything `AdvancedFunction1` did.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is called *upcasting*. Upcasting is when you take a pointer to a derived type and try to assign it to a base type. It doesn't work.

You are only allowed to implicitly cast a pointer to a pointer of a type of one of its base classes. You can cast either a `TestB*` or a `TestC*` to a `TestA*`, but you cannot implicitly cast a `TestB*` to a `TestC*`, or a `TestA*` to either of its subclasses. So your example wouldn't even compile.

The reason is that, as in your example, if you could cast base pointers to derived pointers, you could call derived functions on base pointers, and that would cause many problems because you would try to access the derived's member variables and they wouldn't be there.

You can do this by an explicit cast, but if you do, you'll most likely get a segfault if the underlying type really isn't derived from the base type you're casting it to. You can do this safely with `dynamic_cast` if your class is polymorphic, which returns `NULL` when you try to cast a derived pointer to a base pointer of a type that it isn't derived from.

Answer (score 1):

> TestB *Advanced1 = &Basic; //Is this viable?

No, because upcasting is not a good idea.

You should use polymorphism, by creating a virtual function in your base and then overriding the function in Derived.

If you want to use your variable A in your derived classes, you should make it protected, because you cannot use it by public inheritance if it is private.

Comment: Pointers don't slice. Slicing is when you use the copy constructor of a base class on an instance of a derived class.

Comment: Sorry. I intended it for it to be protected and not private. Force of habit. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: SSight3: I meant upcasting, downcasting isn't a problem, but when upcasting, your types will be incompatible

Comment: Oh, isn't that *Downcasting*? *Upcasting* is implicitly allowed, A pointer to Base class can always point an object of Derived class, publically derived from it. That is *Upcasting*, This is opposite of that, Derived class pointer pointing to object of Base class, Thats *Downcasting*.

Comment: Updated, hth, need to run for now, yeay end of days play at work ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would not do this - use inheritance properly, i.e.

```
TestA* Advanced1 = new TestB;
TestA* Advanced2 = new TestC;

// your previous code at this point is wrong - these functions should be virtual in base class and overridden in derived classes...
Advanced1->AdvancedFunction1(); // This now does what you want
Advanced2->AdvancedFunction2(); // and so does this...
```

The assignment is fine...

The problem with your approach is what happens if you have virtual functions (multiple inheritance), or at some point you decide that `TestB` needs members etc. It's a wrong approach on so many levels...

Comment: Thank you for the input. They only modify copies of themselves. I was thinking more a centralised base class that more advanced functions can modify then return.

Answer (score 1):

No.

First of all, the methods aren't static in your example so you can't access them from the class type. You need an instance of an object.

Now lets assume you meant:

```
Advanced1->AdvancedFunction1(); 
Advanced2->AdvancedFunction2();
```

`TestB` publicly extends `TestA`, so it has all its functionality and more. So `TestB` **is a** `TestA`.

But `TestA` **is not a** `TestB`, so you can't assign a `TestA` to a `TestB`.

So the problem with that is shown clearly here, **Advanced1** and **Advanced2** point at an object of type `Base` which does not have that method at all. So you can't point at something with less functionality than the type the variable is declared.

Comment: Yes, I had meant that. Brain not in gear. Corrected. Why can't you point at it, given TestB supplies the function?

Comment: Because the types you set in the compiler are just there for type safety (a lot of script languages for example don't require type safety). So though the variable a pointer to that type, the actual object is not. In your case you clearly created an object of the base class which does not have that method.

Answer (score 1):

The above code summons the daemon of **Undefined Behaviour**. It is formally invalid code (provided you add the `static_cast` without which it won't compile) and the compiler will be happy to invent way how to turn your cat black instead.

Gcc is especially renowned for it's creativity in punishing programmers who dare to summon the beast. In your case it would be quite likely to either constant-propagate the same values into both functions because specification says that Advanced1 and Advanced2 can't point to the same object or optimize the calls away because specification says neither can point to the same object as Basic despite all indications that they actually do. And believe me, if it does something like this deep in some creative code, it is *very* hard to debug.

Note, that since the functions are not virtual, there is absolutely no difference between methods and (possibly overloaded) free functions except formal ones. So there is nothing preventing you to simply write:

```
void AdvancedFunction1(TestA &that) { that.A = that.A + that.A; }
```

and than:

```
TestA test;
AdvancedFunction1(test);
```

On a side-note: It is very, very silly behaviour to completely rework the question when you already have some answers. The first version of the question had Advanced1 and Advanced2 and Basic and now it has altogether different names.

Comment: But surely the behaviour is theoretically defined? TestB/TestC are no bigger than TestA, they use the same variable and it's only functions that are expanded. I could see a problem if TestB/TestC had extra variables, but they won't for obvious reasons.

Comment: @SSight3: The dreaded daemon of Undefined Behaviour is summoned when you do something that The Holy Specification says is undefined. Ergo it's *theoretically undefined* (it may well be "practically defined" in a particular implementation). The most dangerous cases are when you do something, that is formally undefined, but you for the life of you can't see how the compiler can do anything else than TheObviousThing™, because GCC proves every day that for every undefined behaviour there is a clever optimization that relies on that restriction.

Comment: But isn't this precisely how variable arguments work in vprintf at the lowest level? A pointer from function arguments that is interpretively recast as something else? Isn't this how a class is converted into binary byte-by-byte (char) data? In a sense I am not even modifying the core base class, just the functions, which would be theoretically no different than if they were externalised.

Comment: @SSight3: No, it's not. `vprintf` has to be told exactly what types you gave it, otherwise you invoke Undefined Behaviour. Reading binary data is allowed because cv-qualified `char *` is explicitly exempt from aliasing rules. Beyond that pointer may only point to variable that is of the same or derived type and two pointers may only point to the same object if they are the same type or one is derived type of the other. Gcc can be very creative in abusing you if you violate this (it will reorder the code until it makes no sense).

Answer (score 1):

```
TestA Basic;
TestB *Advanced1 = &Basic; //Is this viable?
TestC *Advanced2 = &Basic; //And this?
```

No, a child cannot point to an object of father type.

```
TestB->AdvancedFunction1(); //Does this do what I think it does?
TestC->AdvancedFunction2(); //Or do implicit errors/problems occur?
```

It calls TestB::AdvancedFunction1 (that is if you had forced (cast) &Basic to Advanced1). Results may be catastrophic.

```
TestB AdvVar1;
TestC AdvVar2;

AdvVar1 = Basic; //Does this do what is intended? 
AdvVar2 = Basic; //Or do implicit errors occur?
```

Not at all. Although sometimes it may be reasonable to down-cast (cast a father to child), copying (unless operator = is defined) doesn't work.

What you should do, if you want to have a list of children all with pointers to father, here's what you should do:

```
class TestA
{
public:
    enum _type
    {
         IS_TESTA = 0,
         IS_TESTB,
         IS_TESTC
    } type;
    /* other variables */
    TestA() {type = IS_TESTA;}
    virtual void common_function() { /* do something with TestA data */ }
    void father_function() {}
}

class TestB : public TestA
{
public:
    /* variables */
    TestB() {type = TestA::IS_TESTB;}
    void common_function() { /* do something with TestA & TestB data */ }
    void TestB_specific_function() {}
}

class TestC : public TestA
{
public:
    /* variables */
    TestC() {type = TestA::IS_TESTC;}
    void common_function() { /* do something with TestA & TestC data */ }
    void TestC_specific_function() {}
}
```

To create the list, you do this:

```
TestA **list = new TestA *[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    if (for_any_reason_create_TestB)
        list[i] = new TestB;
    else if (for_any_reason_create_TestC)
        list[i] = new TestC;
    else
        list[i] = new TestA;
```

Now, when you want to use the variables, when you want to call the function shared by all, even though each subclass has implemented it differently, you could do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    list[i]->common_function();
```

And it would automatically call `TestA::common_function`, `TestB::common_function` or `TestC::common_function` depending on the real object type.

If you want to call specific children functions, you could do this (but is not recommended):

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    if (list[i]->type == TestA::IS_TESTB)
        ((TestB *)list[i])->TestB_specific_function();
    else if (list[i]->type == TestA::IS_TESTC)
        ((TestC *)list[i])->TestC_specific_function();
```

Comment: Thank you for the indepth answer.